# Why is my array not ordering in the manner in which I push the objects into the Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Okay I have a slight problem with a javascript array of objects the array would look something like this:

```
var myArray = [
           {Month : 1, Count : 1000},
           {Month : 2, Count : 1000},
           {Month : 9, Count : 1000},
           {Month : 10, Count : 1000},
           {Month : 11, Count : 1000},
           {Month : 12, Count : 1000},
     ];
```

The problem I am having is that I am using this array of objects to display data
to a graph. For the life of me I have attempted every way that I can think of to reorder this array in the manner that I need. that need being something like this:

```
________________________________________________
 09       10       11       12        1        2
```

because the graph is supposed to be showing 6 months of data in reverse order starting with the current month. I have tried several things including this:

```
   Code Updated Below:
```

The calling of the method and loading it with an array of objects:

```
<script>

monthArray = [];
        monthArray.push({"Month" : 1,
            "Count" : 1252});
        monthArray.push({"Month" : 2,
            "Count" : 1252});
        monthArray.push({"Month" : 9,
            "Count" : 1252});
        monthArray.push({"Month" : 10,
            "Count" : 1252});
        monthArray.push({"Month" : 11,
            "Count" : 1252});
        monthArray.push({"Month" : 12,
            "Count" : 1252});

sTest(monthArray);
</script>
```

which gave me the same result all over again:::

```
   Updated Below:
```

Right now I am doing this all in a regular html file for testing purposes.
Is there no good way to do this, I would try another way but honestly I don't know of any other ways.

For reference the second part of this code has to remain as it is unless someone knows a better way to load a json object into this form of data, basically it is just a mimicry of what I am doing to convert my json object so I can effectively rename the months and the data before loading them to the d3.js bar chart that I am using.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I have recently tried editing the code to concatenate two arrays and display the concatenated array but still received the same result. Here is the new Code:

```
<script>
var sTest = function(array) {

    var newArray = [];
    var newArray2 = [];
    var currentMonth = 2;
    var index = -1;

    //loop through the array to grab the index of the current date to set 
    //my starting and ending points for loading the new array
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        document.write(array[i].Month + "<br/>");
        if (array[i].Month === currentMonth) {
            index = i;
        }
    }

    //test the index of the current date
    document.write("The index of the current date is: " + index + "<br/>");

    //test the length just to be sure and avoid out of bounds errors
    document.write("The length of the current array is: " + array.length + "<br/>");

    //Get the data after the current month and load it to the array first
    for (j = index + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
        newArray.push({"Month" : array[j].Month, "Count" : array[j].Count});
    }    

    //get the data up to the current month and load it into the new array last
    for (k = 0; k <= index; k++) {
        newArray2.push({"Month" : array[k].Month, "Count" : array[k].Count});
    }

    var finalArray = newArray.concat(newArray2);

    //test the printout of the new array to examine the results
    for (i = 0; i < finalArray.length; i++) {
        document.write("Month: " + array[i].Month + " Count: " + array[i].Count + "<br/>");
    }

};
</script>
```

And here is the same result:

```
1
2
9
10
11
12
The index of the current date is: 1
The length of the current array is: 6

Month: 1 Count: 1252
Month: 2 Count: 1252
Month: 9 Count: 1252
Month: 10 Count: 1252
Month: 11 Count: 1252
Month: 12 Count: 1252
```

Comment: Your question title asks about an array that **doesn't** reorder itself (which arrays don't do anyway) but your question looks like the arrays you create are _not_ reordering themselves (which is what I would expect). Right now I don't know at all what you're asking because the title and the question seem to be contradictory.

Comment: @StephenP How would I clarify the question? I am a little lost on this myself, I deliberately pushed the necessary data in the order that I needed it in the array and still got the same result as before. With that in mind I have also tried creating two separate arrays and concatenating them and still didn't get the expected result.

Comment: @StephenP Okay I have changed the question title hopefully to be a little less misleading. My question is how would I put the month integers into the array in a form that matches a last six months view. I have tried several ways but even after deliberately pushing them into the array in a certain order (9,10,11,12,1,2) the array still comes out in numerical order (1,2,9,10,11,12) and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```
//test the printout of the new array to examine the results
for (i = 0; i < finalArray.length; i++) {
    document.write("Month: " + array[i].Month + " Count: " + array[i].Count + "<br/>");
}
```

You are looping through `finalArray.length` but your document.write is using `array[i]` **not** `newArray[i]` — you are looping over the original unmodified array.

Comment: HAHAHAHA freaking copy paste got me on that one. I am deeply sorry, it definitely was an overlooked error on my part, I don't know what I was thinking or why I kept overlooking it. I shouldn't have been so ignorant to think I could get away with copy pasting and not incurring errors. I have really got to slow down. This is a classic "I got in a hurry" and just completely messed myself up. I don't know what I was thinking!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you can change a little bit the array, here is one solution:

1. Add a new parameter in the object called Order.
2. "Fix" the month and assign it to the order (as the current month will be the last one, any month with a higher value is from the previous year, reduce its value by 12).
3. Sort the array by the new Order value.

The code would be like this:

```
var date = new Date();
var currentMonth = date.getMonth()+1; // months go from 0 to 11, but your code is 1-12

// add the new ordering parameter
for (var x = 0; x < myArray.length; x++) {
    if (myArray[x].Month > currentMonth) {
        myArray[x].Order = myArray[x].Month - 12;
    } else {
        myArray[x].Order = myArray[x].Month;
    }
}

// sort the array using the new Order value
myArray.sort(function compare(a,b) {
              if (a.Order < b.Order)
                 return -1;
              else
                 return 1;
            });
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/ypp9kc9y/

---

And here a "cleaner" solution that merges all of that into the compare function, and doesn't need additional variables:

```
// sort the array using the new Order value
myArray.sort(function compare(a,b) {
          var date = new Date();
          var orderA = a.Month > date.getMonth()+1 ? a.Month -12 : a.Month;
          var orderB = b.Month > date.getMonth()+1 ? b.Month -12 : b.Month;
          if (orderA < orderB)
             return -1;
          else
             return 1;
        });
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/ypp9kc9y/1/

Comment: This is ingenious, Freaking ingenious. I really wish I would have thought of something like this, this is awesome!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the properties of the [date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) in JavaScript. If you use date math, rather than integer math, then 1/15 will come after 12/14.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion using the term Date was a little ambiguous, I have updated the question to resemble what I am actually doing. The Month in the array object is just an integer which I will convert to the month name on the call to the view. My problem is that every time I try to order the list so that anything that is greater than the current month is displayed behind the current month in the form of a "Last six months view" but I can't seem to get it to work out.